# Error al eliminar un archivo en C# Creando Sistema de Actualizacion

Tags: c#, actualizacion

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente.

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de actualizaciones y para ello debo de eliminar el archivo para reemplazarlo por la nueva version. El problema es que el archivo se encuentra en uso... 
Actualmente cuento con 2 archivos en 1 carpeta, uno llamado Supreme.exe y el otro SupremeUpdate.exe

Este es el codigo del Supreme.exe

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        UpdateProcess();
    }
    static void UpdateProcess()
    {
        //Get latest and current versions
        string pid = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id.ToString();
        string assemblyVersion = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:/Program Files/Supreme/Supreme.exe").GetName().Version.ToString();
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        string latestVersionWC = wc.DownloadString("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        string currentVersion = assemblyVersion.Replace(".", "");
        string latestVersion = latestVersionWC.Replace(".", "");
        int cv = Convert.ToInt32(currentVersion);
        int lv = Convert.ToInt32(latestVersion);

        if (cv >= lv)
        {
            Application.Run(new SupremePicker());
        }
        else
        {
            Process.Start(@"C:/Program Files/Supreme/SupremeUpdate.exe");
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

y este es el del SupremeUpdater.exe

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new formUpdate());
    }
```

Estoy intentando dentro del formUpdate eliminar el archivo Supreme.exe de la carpeta con el siguiente codigo:

```
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME.exe"))
                {
                    File.Delete(@"C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME.exe");
                }
                File.Move(@"C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME_Latest.txt", @"C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME.exe");
                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME.exe");
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al eliminar o renombrar el archivo");
            }
```

pero este me arroja un error dentro del catch. No entiendo por que si dentro del codigo de Supreme.exe escribi Application.Exit(); para que se finalice. Tambien probé intentar cerrarlo con el PID correspondiente pero aun asi me sigue dejando el mismo error.

Concretamente el error me lo da el File.Delete...

Si alguien fuera tan amable de ayudarme... me falta solo esto para terminar mi sistema de updates...

Comment: mostra qu error da.. el error real, saca el catch y fijate cual es el error que te esta dando...

Comment: Me dice Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso C:\Program Files\Supreme\SUPREME.exe a pesar de que se ejecuta como administrador. (Tengo el AV desactivado)

Comment: en el delete,en el move o en el start?

Comment: me lo arroja en el delete

Comment: si detenes el programa y esperas (a veces los delete, move y otras cosas tardan), te sigue dando el error?

Comment: Quieres que agregue un Thread.Sleep? voy a hacerlo te confirmo en 2 min

Comment: Si, definitivamente es el File.Delete ya que el resto de codigo me pasa bien... debere abrir un cmd para eliminarlo desde ahi? sigue diciendo Persmiso denegado a la carpeta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106398/discussion-between-gby-and-gbianchi).

Comment: Siempre que detengas un proceso porque vayas a actualizar debes meter un timer de unos segundos para dar tiempo a que el proceso finalice correctamente. En tu programa actualizador, lanzar el kill al programa principal.... un timer de unos 3 segundos y ya haces el delete y el copy del nuevo